# Gzip not working in Apache using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, compression, gzip

Gzip not working in php apache via .htaccess file

```
   RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

      # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
      BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
      Header append Vary User-Agent
    </IfModule>
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On 
    # Default directive
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    </IfModule>
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Explanation: When i test using compression test(https://checkgzipcompression.com/) its showing not enabled and site is still slow.some one pls help to sort out this problem

Comment: Silly question: is mod_deflate enabled?

Comment: everything is enabled.i got it i removed these codes from .htaccess and added below code to my header file                                                            if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start();

Comment: Which will only do the job for the dynamic pages but not the static files.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the above codes from .htaccess and added below code to my header file

if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); 
else`enter code here`
 ob_start();